# Reload activity on tab changed

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs, android-tabactivity

I have this activity in a tabhost and I need to reload it when I change to another tab, and came back to this activity, for my listview can refresh with the new items. Can anybody tell me how can I do this.

Here is my favorites activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.favorites);
        initialize();

    }

    private void initialize(){
        list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.fav_listView1);
        back=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.favorites_back_img);
        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();               
            }
        });
        helper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
        helper.openDB();
        adapter=new AlbumLazyAdapter(this, helper.getAllFavorites(), this);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `initialize()` method in `onResume()`.

Comment: Welcome Bozidar Prcovski :)

Comment: initialize() is not a predefined method